# Kendo: DropDownList not binding to model.string property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using **KendoUI** on **MVC4**.

I have a **DropDownList** bound to a **model** property that is a empty string:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.AppUserStatus)
                                      .Name("userStatusDropDownList")
                                      .DataTextField("Text")
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:100%;"})
                                      .DataValueField("Value")
                                      .BindTo(@ViewBag.StatusList))
```

**model.AppUserStatus** is a string that is empty by default.

After the user selects a new item , or leaves the selected item as the default item (index 0) and posts the form back, the model.AppUserStatus is empty still, even though all the other fields are correctly bound:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update(EditUserViewModel model)
    {
        model.AppUserStatus ***** IS Null always, all other fields are good
        return View("EditUser", model);
    }
```

Comment: Does it work with Html.DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set Name("userStatusDropDownList") property for control.

Remove it and the name will be auto generated properly - i.e. **#AppUserStatus**.

This Name method also controls the name by the value that is posted to the server - the name attribute of the input element which is posted.

Comment: Correct. If you leave .Name("userStatusDropDownList") then it will overwrite (model => model.AppUserStatus) which will cause you to have an empty/null value in the controller.